# Convert SQL query SELECT SUM into laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have this SQL query

```
select sum(repayment_borrower.settle_amount+ repayment_borrower.settle_interest + repayment_borrower.settle_penalty) as Total Default
     FROM repayment_borrower,loans,loan_offer, lender
     WHERE repayment_borrower.loans_id = loans.id
     AND loan_offer.loan_id = loans.id
     AND loans.lnsts <> 999
     AND loans.lnsts = 810
     AND loan_offer.lender_id = lender.id
     and lender.user_id = "3"
```

This code work when I apply in sql phpmyadmin. But, when I convert at laravel like this

```
$count_badloans        =  DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT sum(repayment_borrower.settle_amount+ repayment_borrower.settle_interest + repayment_borrower.settle_penalty) as Total Default
                                                    FROM repayment_borrower,loans,loan_offer, lender
                                                    WHERE repayment_borrower.loans_id = loans.id
                                                    AND loan_offer.loan_id = loans.id
                                                    AND loans.lnsts <> 999
                                                    AND loans.lnsts = 810
                                                    AND loan_offer.lender_id = lender.id
                                                    and lender.user_id = $userId ") );
```

an error occurred like this

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFdue.png)

am I wrong to apply the query to the laravel? Please help.....

thanks in advance.

Comment: when you converted your query to laravel you removed the quotation around Total Default? i don't use laravel so correct me if i'm wrong but isn't that still a syntax error?

Comment: I've been remove quotation and edited the question. but still getting the same eror

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do like this, Set Total Default to Total_Default (without space) Or simple Total

```
$count_badloans  =  DB::select("SELECT sum(repayment_borrower.settle_amount+ repayment_borrower.settle_interest + repayment_borrower.settle_penalty) as Total 
                                                FROM repayment_borrower,loans,loan_offer, lender
                                                WHERE repayment_borrower.loans_id = loans.id
                                                AND loan_offer.loan_id = loans.id
                                                AND loans.lnsts <> 999
                                                AND loans.lnsts = 810
                                                AND loan_offer.lender_id = lender.id
                                                and lender.user_id = $userId ");
```

Comment: I use this to display data in view : {{$count_badloans}}

Comment: This query return array so use print_r($count_badloans); to print data

Comment: Read total like this {{ $count_badloans[0]->Total; }}

Comment: Wow it's great!! it work right now. I use  {{ $count_badloans[0]->Total }}   ....Big thanks for you @Komal

Answer (score 0):

@arbong Can you remove the alias name `Total Default` ?

```
$count_badloans        =  DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT
  SUM(repayment_borrower.settle_amount + repayment_borrower.settle_interest + repayment_borrower.settle_penalty)
FROM repayment_borrower,
     loans,
     loan_offer,
     lender
WHERE repayment_borrower.loans_id = loans.id
AND loan_offer.loan_id = loans.id
AND loans.lnsts <> 999
AND loans.lnsts = 810
AND loan_offer.lender_id = lender.id
AND lender.user_id = $userId "));
```

Comment: getting error like this : htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: C:\laragon\www\klikacc\resources\views\account\me_buyer.blade.php)

Comment: I use this to display data in view : {{$count_badloans}}